# how could i return multiple values from a function in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, tuples

Is it possible for a function to return multiple values – e.g., a string and a Boolean?

If yes, then I have a function called `concat` which returns a `Bool` and a `String`, but I don't know how to call that function so I can store the result.

Example attempt:

```
concat::(String->Int)->(IO Bool->IO String)
concat line i=do
       return True line
```

Can you help me to write the function signature and how to call those functions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When returning multiple values you have to return an algebraic data type. Much can be said about this, I will give you some suggestions.

1. If your `Bool` and `String` are somehow more related and they will be often together in your code, define a new algebraic data type:

   ```
   data Question = Question Bool String
   ```

   You can define it also with accessor functions, which document the data as well:

   ```
   data Question = Question{ answered :: Bool
                           , text     :: String }
   ```

   and you can define a function e. g. for initializing question:

   ```
   question :: String -> Question
   question str = Question False (str ++ "?")
   ```

   or (for improved documentation):

   ```
   question :: String -> Question
   question str = Question{ answered = False
                          , text     = str ++ "?"}
   ```

   then you can work with your data using data constructor:

   ```
   answer :: String -> Question -> Question
   answer answ (Question False str) =
     Question True (str ++ " " ++ answ ++ ".")
   answer _ old = old
   ```

   or using the accessor functions (many combinations of the two approaches are possible):

   ```
   answer :: String -> Question -> Question
   answer answ qstn
     | answered qstn = qstn
     | otherwise     = qstn{ answered = True
                           , text     = text qstn ++ " " ++ answ ++ "."}
   ```

   example of calling the functions:

   ```
   answer "Yes it is" (question "Is this answer already too long")
   ```
2. If you don't want to define a new data type use a predefined one - tuple. There are many functions defined in standard libraries, which make your work with tuples easier. However, don't use the tuples everywhere - bigger code would become a mess (lack of documentation - it's not clear what data the tuple represents), type errors would not be so easy to trace due to polymorphism.

   An example of a kind-of-convenient use of tuples:

   ```
   squareAndCube :: Int -> (Int, Int)
   squareAndCube x = (square, square*x)
     where square = x*x

   sumOfSquareAndCube :: Int -> Int
   sumOfSquareAndCube x = square + cube
     where (square, cube) = squareAndCube x
   ```

   Too much said about this simple question but since I mentioned the standard library support as the main advantage of tuples, I'll give the last example which uses `uncurry` function from Prelude:

   ```
   sumOfSquareAndCube :: Int -> Int
   sumOfSquareAndCube x = uncurry (+) (squareAndCube x)
   ```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can return multiple values with a haskell construct called a tuple.

Here's a simple example

```
addAndSub :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
addAndSub a b = (a + b, a - b)
```

You can then access the first part of the tuple with `fst` and the second with `snd`. However it's preferable to pattern match

```
use = case addAndSub 2 3 of
  (i, j) -> i + j
```

or

```
let (i,j) = addAndSub 2 3 
in i + j
```

Now let's say your function does some IO and gets a `String` and an `Bool`, your function would then look vaguely like

```
magic :: IO (String, Bool)
magic = do
  string <- getString
  bool   <- getBool
  return (string, bool)
```

If you're working in a monad with and using a `do` block, you can also pattern match using a prettier form.

```
foo = do
 (i, j) <- magic
```

Notice that this *has to be in a do block*. You can only use a do block if you're returning a value with the type `m a` where `m` is a monad, like `IO`.

Comment: i dont want to use the case can i write this way

Comment: @rahul Write which way?

Comment: @rahul I've updated. Do not that you can't use do blocks everywhere, only when doing something like `IO`. Why don't you like the `case` form?

Comment: i need to implement the recursion to find the path Thats why i do nt want to use case

Comment: @rahul The second form I posted is really just a case with sugar, so you can use either.

Comment: Just a nitpick, in the last example `do` block need end with an expression like `return (i, j)` which would be then pointless - without `a` transormation wrapping back in `m a`.